# waiting for AM container to be allocated, launched and register with RM

Tags: hadoop

When I started hadoop example wordcount, it stuck at 'Running job: job_1502778007453_0001'. The following pictures show the detail:
[image]

And the log shows that there is 0 MB allocated:
[image]

I have tried many methods related to this but none of them work. Does anyone know how to figure it out?

Comment: Do you have several jobs running in parallel ? I see your job is using 'default' queue. Please check utilization of 'default' queue when your job is in accepted state. If queue does not have capacity then job will have no resources allocated and will not be in running state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me the following did the trick:

edit $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/capacity-scheduler.xml and change the following property value from 0.1 to something higher. I changed to 0.5 (50%)

```
<property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.maximum-am-resource-percent</name>
    <value>0.5</value>
    <description>
        Maximum percent of resources in the cluster which can be used to run application masters i.e. controls number of concurrent running applications.
    </description>
</property>
```

You may have to allocate more memory to YARN by editing yarn-site.xml by updating the following property:

```
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
    <value>8192</value>
</property>
```

Comment: Thanks, setting  both yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores to 4 and  yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb to 4096 makes it work.